# Nested Hashmap updates all the values for all the keys instead the one I want to change

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a hashmap that contains 10 children hashmap, each of these child hashmap 5 keys mapping to a String array. When I want to update a value for a specific key from a children hashmap, all the keys get updated instead; not only that, but also all the children hashmap get updated as well. This code illustrate what I'm doing.

```
HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String[]>> parentMap = new HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String[]>>();

for(String x : someArray){ // Adds 10 children hashmaps to parentMap
    parentMap.put(x,new HashMap<String, String[]>());
    for(String y : someOtherArray){ // Creates 5 keys for each of the children hashmaps
        parentMap.get(x).put(y,stringArray);
    }
}

parentMap.get(someKey).put(someOtherKey,modifiedArray); // This updates the entry I want to update.
```

When I update with that last instruction, I want to update specifically that key, however everything gets updated instead, all the keys for all the children hashmaps are updated instead the one I want.

Hopefully it makes sense, I'm not sure if this is the correct approach for this but I've been looking online for any tips on doing something similar without any luck. I'm not good at all with Java,  if I can achieve the same result with something simpler, it will be welcome, note that I can't use a List or something like that, since it uses int indexes, I need to reference to my objects using a string (like a dictionary on python).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is because you initialize all maps to contain `stringArray`, i.e., **the same array**.

This is why changing one of them, will change all of them.

If you want each key in each inner map to point to *different copies* of the array, you need to do something like

```
...
    parentMap.get(x).put(y, Arrays.copyOf(stringArray, stringArray.length));
                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
...
```

(You could also use for instance `clone` or create new arrays manually each time you need a new copy.)

Comment: Thanks aioobe! This resolved my problem ! I didn't have an idea that HashMaps behaves like this. It kind of reminds me of C pointers.

Answer (score 0):

@aioobe explained the reason.

Here is the solution. You have to create copy of initial array every time you put it into your map:

```
String[] tmpArr = new String[stringArray.length];
arraycopy(stringArr, 0, tmpArr, 0, stringArray.length);
parentMap.get(x).put(y,stringArray);
```

Comment: Thanks for your time ! I'm using an implentation very similar to this when updating the values of the children hashmaps.